# exposing operations on resources RESTfully - overloaded POST vs. PUT vs. controller resources

Tags: rest

Say you've got a Person resource, and part of its representation includes a Location value which can have values like "at home", "at school" and "at work".  How would you RESTfully expose activities like  "go home", "go to work", "go to school", etc?  For the sake of discussion, let's stipulate that these activities take time, so they are executed asynchronously, and there are various ways in which they could fail (no means of transportation available, transportation breakdown during travel, other act of God, etc.).  In addition, the Person resource has other attributes and associated operations that affect those attributes (e.g. attribute=energy-level, operations=eat/sleep/excercise).

**Option 1**: Overload POST on the Person resource, providing an input parameter indicating what you want the person to do (e.g. action=go-to-school).  Return a 202 from the POST and expose activity-in-progress status attributes within the Person's representation that the client can GET to observe progress and success/failure.

*Benefits:* keeps it simple.

*Drawbacks:* amounts to tunneling.  The action taking place is buried in the payload instead of being visible in the URI, verb, headers, etc.  The POST verb on this resource doesn't have a single semantic meaning.

**Option 2**: Use PUT to set the Person's location to the state you'd like them to have.  Return a 202 from the PUT and expose activity-in-progress attributes for status polling via GET.

*Benefits*: Not sure I see any.

*Drawbacks*: really, this is just tunneling with another verb.  Also, it doesn't work in some cases (both sleeping and eating increase energy-level, so PUTting the energy-level to a higher value is ambiguous in terms of what action you want the resource to perform).

**Option 3**: expose a generic controller resource that operates on Person objects.  For example, create a PersonActivityManager resource that accepts POST requests with arguments that identify the target Person and requested action.  The POST could return a PersonActivity resource to represent the activity in progress, which the client could GET to monitor progress and success/failure.

*Benefits*: Seems a bit cleaner by separating the activity and its status from the Person resource.

*Drawbacks*: Now we've moved the tunneling to the PersonActivityManager resource.

**Option 4**:
Establish separate controller resources for each supported action, e.g. a ToWorkTransporter resource that accepts POST requests with an argument (or URI element) that identifies the Person, plus a ToHomeTransporter, a ToSchoolTransporter, a MealServer, a Sleeper, and an Exerciser.  Each of these returns an appropriate task-monitoring resource (Commute, Meal, Slumber, Workout) from their POST method, which the client can monitor via GET.

*Benefits*: OK, we've finally eliminated tunneling.  Each POST means only one thing.

*Drawbacks*: Now were talking about a lot of resources (maybe we could combine the transporters into one Transporter that accepts a destination argument).  And some of them are pretty semantically contrived (a Sleeper?).  It may be more RESTful, but is it practical?

Comment: Why would you think that putting an action in a resource name is a good idea? POST means “do something based on this document”, but if the documents are different then the triggered action can be too.

Comment: Exposing processes as resources is a commonly-encountered recommendation in RESTful design conversations. In RESTful Web Services (O'Reilly) the authors suggest "if you're tempted to expose complex objects or processes through overloaded POST, try giving the objects or processes their own URIs, and exposing them as resources".  In RESTful Web Services Cookbook (O'Reilly), in recipe 2.6, the author says "Designate a controller resource for each distinct operation".  In REST In Practice (also O'Reilly) the author describes a coffee shop system with a Order resource accepting POSTs.

Comment: A similar post with interesting answers: [REST API design for non-CRUD actions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742926/389489)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

OK, I've been researching and pondering this for about a week now.  Since nobody else has answered, I'll post the results of what I've learned.

Tim Bray, in [RESTful Casuistry](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2009/03/20/Rest-Casuistry),  talks about PUT-ing a state field vs POST-ing to a controller which will perform an operation affecting that state.  He uses the example of a VM and how to RESTfully expose the function of a "reboot button".  He says

> "If I want to update some fields in an existing resource, I’m inclined
>   to think about PUT. But that doesn’t work because it’s supposed to be
>   idempotent, and rebooting a server sure isn’t. Well, OK, do it with
>   POST I guess; no biggie.
>
> But you’re not really changing a state, you’re requesting a specific
>   set of actions to happen, as a result of which the state may or may
>   not attain the desired value. In fact, when you hit the deploy switch,
>   the state changes to deploying and then after some unpredictable
>   amount of time to deployed. And the reboot operation is the classic
>   case of a box with a big red switch on the side; the problem is how to
>   push the switch.
>
> So, the more I think of it, the more I think that these resources are
>   like buttons, with only one defined operation: push. People have been
>   whining about “write-only resources” but I don’t have a problem with
>   that because it seems accurate. The reboot and halt buttons don’t
>   really have any state, so you shouldn’t expect anything useful from a
>   GET."

Tim seems to settle somewhere between my #3 and #4 option, exposing multiple controller resources, but pulling back from "going overboard" and having separate controller resources for everything.

Tim's post led to another by Roy Fielding ([It is OK to use POST](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)) in which he says that for situations where there is a monitorable entity state, and an action to potentially change that state, he's inclined to use POST rather than PUT.  In response to a commenter's suggestion to expose the monitored state as a separate PUT-able resource, he says

> "we only use PUT when the update action is idempotent and the
>   representation is complete. I think we should define an additional
>   resource whenever we think that resource might be useful to others in
>   isolation, and make use of the GET/PUT methods for that resource, but
>   I don’t think we should define new resources just for the sake of
>   avoiding POST."

Finally, Bill de hOra, in [Just use POST](http://www.dehora.net/journal/2009/02/03/just-use-post/) discusses the specific case of using PUT vs. POST to update the state of a collection resource, and the tradeoffs therein.

Comment: Since it's been a while now and there are no other answers, I'm accepting this one.

Comment: It's not exactly clear which solution you chose. Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: @KennethCochran Ha, this was 7 years ago, so it's not fresh in my mind... but I think I went in the direction of Tim Bray's approach.

Comment: I really enjoyed your exercise @AndyDennie, actually about 10 years later I find myself dwelling amongst the same doubts. And even though by your elaborate example it seems to me it that this API you were talking about would be better changed to RPC instead of REST, I understand that the third solution(#3) is actually the most accurate, once it truly keeps it restful through the controller resource concept, which by my studies so far seems to be a restful proven concept, what you think?